# How to get the detector information from the COM interface of VISSIM

Tags: c#, com-interface

How can I get the state of the detector from the COM interface of VISSIM?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detectors, or as Vissim calls it, Data Collection Measurements can be fetched from COM using the command:

```
Detector = Vissim.Net.DataCollectionMeasurements.ItemByKey(detector ID)
```

Then you can check for the required values, if equipped using this command:

```
Speed = Detector.AttValue('Speed(Current,Avg,All)')
```

This will retrieve the current average speed for all the lanes.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about C#, but I know how to get the state of detectors from COM-interface of VISSIM.

`sim = CreateObject("VISSIM.Vissim.700")`

`Detector=sim.net.Detectors`

```
Set deton = dets.itembykey(1)
```

if you want to know, whether the detector is impulse or not

```
a=deton.attvalue("Impulse")
```

if you want to know, the speed of vehicles which is detected by this detectors then

```
b=detup1.attvalue("VehSpeed")
```

Then output the resu

```
guiSheet.Range("a1").Value = a
guiSheet.Range("b1").Value = b
```

Please pay attention, you have to define guiSheet as follows

```
guiSheet = Worksheets("VISSIM")
```

Then you can get the status of detector in VISSIM. In addition to speed and Impulse state, you also can find a lot of other states, e.g., occupancy.

I am also a beginner of VISSIM COM-Interface, hope the answer is helpful for you:)

Comment: Yes, it is really helpful for me. Thank you.